# Failed to train with tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Environment:
TF2.0
Python 3.5
ubuntu 16.04

Problem:
I try to use the pre-trained mobilenet_V2 but accuracy doesn't increase:

```py
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
```

The script is copied from the tutorial of the tensorflow 2.0(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning?hl=zh-cn)

The only change I made is the dataset which feed into the network. The original code makes binary classification between dogs and cats, and everything works. However, the accuracy never increases while  using multi-classes datasets like: "mnist", "tf_flowers". Please note that, I used the correct loss function and metrics.

Naive model and results:
[image]

Keras.mobilenetv2:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

keras = tf.keras
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
# tfds.disable_progress_bar()


IMG_SIZE = 224
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

def format_example(image, label):
    if image.shape[-1] == 1:
        image = tf.concat([image, image, image], 2)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = (image/127.5) - 1
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return image, label

##----functional model----##
class TinyModel():
    def __init__(self, num_classes, hiddens=32, input_shape=IMG_SHAPE):
        import tensorflow as tf
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.hiddens = hiddens
    def build(self):
        inputs = Input(shape=self.input_shape)
        x = Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu", strides=2)(inputs)
        x = Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2)(x)
        x = Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2)(x)
        x = Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(x)
        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = Dense(self.hiddens, activation="relu")(x)
        outputs = Dense(self.num_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='my_model')
        return model


def assemble_model(num_classes, model_name='MobileNetV2'):
    import tensorflow as tf 
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                    weights='imagenet',
                                                    include_top=False)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                                base_model,
                                GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                                Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
                                ])
    model.trainable = True
    return model



## ---- dataset preparation -----##
SPLIT_WEIGHTS = (8, 1, 1)
splits = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(weighted=SPLIT_WEIGHTS)

(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers', split=list(splits),
    with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
get_label_name = metadata.features['label'].int2str






train = raw_train.map(format_example)
validation = raw_validation.map(format_example)
test = raw_test.map(format_example)

BATCH_SIZE = 32
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

train_ds = train.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_ds = validation.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_ds = test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)


IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)



## ----- model config ---- ##
# Create an instance of the model
model = TinyModel(num_classes=5).build()   # model 1
# model = assemble_model(num_classes=5)    # model 2
model.summary()


## ----- training config -----##

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')


## ----- training loop -----##
@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(labels, predictions)

@tf.function
def test_step(images, labels):
  predictions = model(images)
  t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

  test_loss(t_loss)
  test_accuracy(labels, predictions)

EPOCHS = 5

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
  train_loss.reset_states()
  train_accuracy.reset_states()
  test_loss.reset_states()
  test_accuracy.reset_states()

  for images, labels in train_ds:
    train_step(images, labels)

  for test_images, test_labels in test_ds:
    test_step(test_images, test_labels)

  template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
  print(template.format(epoch+1,
                        train_loss.result(),
                        train_accuracy.result()*100,
                        test_loss.result(),
                        test_accuracy.result()*100))
```

----------------------**SOLVED**-----------------------
Solution：add the argument "training=True" when training the keras.application.. For example

```py
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,weights="imagenet",include_top=False)

pred = model(inputs, training=True)
```

The reason might be caused by "batchnorm" layer. Those model which has BN layers works well in keras training loop, "model.fit()", and nothing to takecare. However, they cannot learn anything by costume training loop if you forget to set training=True in model()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set all your parameters to be non-trainable, check this on hte summary of the model, you will see something like this

[image]

Change this line, (or just delete it)

```
base_model.trainable = False
```

To

```
base_model.trainable = True
```

And everything will work fine